# Replacing post-cat O2 sensor bmw f30

Tags: bmw, o2-sensor

I am having some difficulties finding the location of post-cat O2 sensor (bank 1 sensor 2) in my car.

As far as I know the one in the picture is the upstrem (pre-cat) sensor and I am not sure where the post-cat is located.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post-cat O2 sensor is going on the on the other end of your cat.

You'll need to SAFELY get the vehicle lifted and get under it and look for the sensor on the output end of your cat.

Comment: So it is under the car (chassis)?

Comment: Yes, it will be under the car.

Comment: something like this https://www.realoem.com/bmw/enUS/showparts?id=FW11-EUR---F10-BMW-520d&diagId=13_1508 ?

Comment: I believe callout #16 is your post-cat O2 sensor.